# How to convert to UInt64 from a string in Powershell? String-to-number conversion

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, powershell-5.0

Consider the following Powershell snippet:

```
[Uint64] $Memory = 1GB
[string] $MemoryFromString = "1GB"
[Uint64] $ConvertedMemory = [Convert]::ToUInt64($MemoryFromString)
```

The 3rd Line fails with:

```
Exception calling "ToUInt64" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:1
+ [Uint64]$ConvertedMemory = [Convert]::ToUInt64($MemoryFromString)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

If I check the contents of `$Memory`:

```
PS C:\> $Memory
1073741824
```

That works fine.

So, how do I convert the value "1GB" from a string to a UInt64 in Powershell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that the `ToUint64` doesn't understand the Powershell syntax. You could get around it by doing:

```
($MemoryFromString / 1GB) * 1GB
```

As the `$MemoryFromString` will be converted its numeric value before the division.

This works because at the point of division Powershell attempts to convert the string to a number using its rules, rather than the .Net rules that are baked into `ToUInt64`. As part of the conversion if spots the `GB` suffix and applies it rules to expand the `"1GB"` string to `1073741824`

EDIT: Or as PetSerAl pointed out, you can just do:

```
($MemoryFromString / 1)
```

Answer (score 14):

To *complement* [Sean's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41088625/45375):

It is only the type constraint of your result variable (`[uint64] $ConvertedMemory` = ...) that ensures that `($MemoryFromString / 1)` is converted to `[uint64]` (`[System.UInt64]`).

The result of expression `$MemoryFromString / 1` is actually of type `[int]` (`[System.Int32]`):

```
PS> ('1gb' / 1).GetType().FullName
System.Int32
```

Therefore, to ensure that the expression *by itself* returns an `[uint64]` instance, you'd have to use a *cast*:

```
PS> ([uint64] ('1gb' / 1)).GetType().FullName
System.Int64
```

<sup>Note the required `(...)` around the calculation, as the `[uint64]` cast would otherwise apply to `'1gb'` only (and therefore fail).

Alternatively, `('1gb' / [uint64] 1)` works too.</sup>

Note:

- `'1gb' - 0` would have worked too,
- but ***not* `'1gb' * 1'` (effectively a no-op) or `'1gb' + 0` (results in string `'1gb0'`)**, because operators `*` and `+` with a *string*-typed LHS perform *string* operations (replication and concatenation, respectively).

---

#### Automatic *string-to-number conversion* and *number literals* in PowerShell:

When PowerShell performs **implicit number conversion**, including when performing mixed-numeric-type calculations and parsing number literals in source code, it **conveniently auto-selects a numeric type that is "large" enough to hold the result**.

In **implicit string-to-number conversions**, PowerShell conveniently recognizes the **same formats as supported in number *literals* in source code**:

- **number-*base* *prefixes*** (for *integers* only): `0x` for *hexadecimal* integers, and `0b` for *binary* integers (PowerShell [Core] 7.0+)
- **number-*type* *suffixes***: `L` for `[long]` (`[System.Int64]`), and `D` for `[decimal]` (`[System.Decimal]`); e.g., `'1L' - 0` yields a `[long]`.
  <sup>Note that **C#** uses `M` instead of `D` and instead uses `D` to designate `[System.Double]`; also, C# supports several additional suffixes.</sup>

  - **PowerShell [Core] 6.2+** now supports **additional suffixes**: `Y` (`[sbyte]`), `UY` (`[byte]`), `S` (`[int16]`), `US` (`[uint16]`), `U` (`[uint32]` *or* `[uint64]`, on demand), and `UL` (`[uint64]`).
  - **PowerShell [Core] 7.0+** additionally suports suffix `n` (`[bigint]`)
  - You can keep an eye on future developments, if any, via the official help topic, [about_Numeric_Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals).
- **floating-point** representations such as `1.23` (*decimal* only); note that **PowerShell only ever recognizes `.` as the decimal mark, *irrespective of the current culture***.
- **exponential notation** (*decimal* only); e.g., `'1.0e3' - 1` yields `999`.
- its own **binary-multiplier suffixes**, `kb`, `mb`, `gb`, `tb`, `pb` (for multipliers `[math]::pow(2, 10)` == `1024`, `[math]::pow(2, 20)` == `1048576`, ...); e.g., `'1kb' - 1` yields `1023`; note that theses suffixes are PowerShell-specific, so the .NET framework number-parsing methods do *not* recognize them.

The **number-conversion rules** are complex, but here are some **key points**:

<sup>This is based on my own experiments. Do tell me if I'm wrong.

Types are expressed by their PS type accelerators and map onto .NET types as follows:

`[int]` ... `[System.Int32]`

`[long]` ... `[System.Int64]`

`[decimal]` ... `[System.Decimal]`

`[float]` ... `[System.Single]`

`[double]` ... `[System.Double]`</sup>

- PowerShell **never auto-selects an *unsigned* integer type**.

  - Note: In *PowerShell [Core] 6.2+*, you can use type suffix `US`, `U` or `UL` (see above) to force treatment as an unsigned type (positive number); e.g., `0xffffffffffffffffU`
  - This can be unexpected with hexadecimal *number literals*; e.g., `[uint32] 0xffffffff` *fails*, because `0xffffffff` is *first* - implicitly - converted to *signed* type `[int32]`, which yields `-1`, which, as a *signed* value, cannot then be cast to *unsigned* type `[uint32]`.
  - Workarounds:

    - Append `L` to force interpretation as an `[int64]` first, which results in expected positive value `4294967295`, in which case the cast to `[uint32]` succeeds.
    - That technique doesn't work for values above `0x7fffffffffffffff` (`[long]::maxvalue`), however, in which case you can use *string* conversion: `[uint64] '0xffffffffffffffff'`
- PowerShell ***widens* integer types as needed**:

  - For **decimal** integer literals / strings, **widening goes *beyond* integer types to `[System.Decimal]`, and then `[Double]`**, as needed; e.g.:

    - `(2147483648).GetType().Name` yields `Int64`, because the value is `[int32]::MaxValue + 1`, and was therefore implicitly widened to `[int64]`.
    - `(9223372036854775808).GetType().Name` yields `Decimal`, because the value is `[int64]::MaxValue + 1`, and was therefore implicitly widened to `[decimal]`.
    - `(79228162514264337593543950336).GetType().Name` yields `Double`, because the value is `[decimal]::MaxValue + 1`, and was therefore implicitly widened to `[double]`.
  - For **hexadecimal** (invariably integer) literals / strings, **widening stops at `[int64]`**:

    - `(0x100000000).gettype().name` yields `Int64`, because the value is `[int32]::MaxValue + 1`, and was therefore implicitly widened to `[int64]`.
    - `0x10000000000000000`, which is `[int64]::MaxValue + 1`, does *not* get promoted to `[System.Decimal]` due to being *hexadecimal* and interpretation as a number therefore *fails*.
  - Note: The above rules apply to individual literals / strings, but widening in *expressions* may result in widening to `[double]` right away (without considering `[decimal]`) - see below.
- PowerShell seemingly **never auto-selects an integer type *smaller* than `[int]`**:

  - `('1' - 0).GetType().FullName` yields `System.Int32` (an `[int]`), even though integer `1` would fit into `[int16]` or even `[byte]`.
- The result of a calculation never uses a smaller type than either of the operands:

  - Both `1 + [long] 1` and `[long] 1 + 1` yield a `[long]` (even though the result could fit into a smaller type).
- Perhaps unexpectedly, **PowerShell auto-selects *floating-point* type `[double]` for a calculation result that is larger than either operand's type *integer* type can fit**, even if the result *could* fit into a *larger integer* type:

  - `([int]::maxvalue + 1).GetType().FullName` yields `System.Double` (a `[double]`), even though the result would fit into a `[long]` integer.
  - If one of the operands is a large-enough integer type, however, the result is of that type: `([int]::maxvalue + [long] 1).GetType().FullName` yields `System.Int64` (a `[long]`).
- **Involving at least one floating-point type in a calculation always results in `[double]`**, even when mixed with an integer type or using all-`[float]` operands:

  - `1 / 1.0` and `1.0 / 1` and `1 / [float] 1` and `[float] 1 / 1` and `[float] 1 / [float] 1` all yield a `[double]`
- **Number *literals* in source code that don't use a type suffix**:

  - ***Decimal* integer** literals are interpreted as **the smallest of the following types that can fit the value: `[int]` > `[long]` > `[decimal]` > `[double]`(!)**:

    - `1` yields an `[int]` (as stated, `[int]` is the smallest auto-selected type)
    - `214748364` (1 higher than `[int]::maxvalue`) yields a `[long]`
    - `9223372036854775808` (1 higher than `[long]::maxvalue`) yields a `[decimal]`
    - `79228162514264337593543950336` (1 higher than `[decimal]::maxvalue`) yields a `[double]`
  - ***Hexadecimal* integer** literals are interpreted as **the smallest of the following types that can fit the value: `[int]` > `[long]`**; that is, unlike with *decimal* literals, types larger than `[long]` aren't supported; **Caveat**: *values that have the high bit set result in *negative* decimal numbers*, because PowerShell auto-selects *signed* integer types:

    - `0x1` yields an `[int]`
    - `0x80000000` yields an `[int]` that is a *negative* value, because the high bit is set: `-2147483648`, which is the *smallest* `[int]` number, if you consider the sign (`[int]::MinValue`)
    - `0x100000000` (1  more than can fit into an `[int]` (or `[uint32]`)) yields a `[long]`
    - `0x10000000000000000` (1  more than can fit into a `[long]` (or `[uint64]`)) *breaks*, because `[long]` is the largest type supported ("the numeric constant is not valid").
    - **To ensure that a hexadecimal literal results in a *positive* number**:

      - Windows PowerShell: Use type suffix `L` to force interpretation as a `[long]` first, and then (optionally) cast to an *unsigned* type; e.g. `[uint32] 0x80000000L` yields `2147483648`, but note that this technique only works up to `0x7fffffffffffffff`, i.e., `[long]::maxvalue`; as suggested above, use a conversion from a *string* as a workaround (e.g., `[uint64] '0xffffffffffffffff'`).
      - PowerShell [Core] 6.2+: Use type suffix `us`, `u`, or `ul`, as needed; e.g.: `0x8000us` -> `32768` (`[uint16]`), `0x80000000u` -> `2147483648` (`[uint32]`), `0x8000000000000000ul` -> `9223372036854775808` (`[uint64]`)
  - ***Binary* integer** literals (PowerShell [Core] 7.0+) are interpreted the same way as *hexadecimal* ones; e.g., `0b10000000000000000000000000000000` == `0x80000000` == `-2147483648` (`[int]`)
  - ***Floating-point* or *exponential notation*** literals (which are only recognized in *decimal* representation) are **always interpreted as a `[double]`**, no matter how small:

    - `1.0` and `1e0` both yield a `[double]`

Comment: Great answer that cleared up a lot for me, thanks for taking the time to put this together.