# Powershell Read-Host Not adding or multiplying correctly?

Tags: powershell

What exactly am I doing wrong here, it seems to be subtracting just fine but adding and multiplying seems to not work at all.

How do I get it to do the calculations correct and allow the if statement to also work as it seems to always run even if the numbers are incorrect size.

```
$a = Read-Host "What is your name?"
$b = Read-Host "Enter a 2 digit number" 
$c = Read-Host "Enter a 3 digit number" 




if (($b -ge 10) -and ($b -le 99) -and ($c -ge 100) -and ($c -le 999)){


$d = $b + $c
$e = $b * $c
$g = $b - $c

$d
$e
$g


Write-host "Here you go $a"

}
else {

write-host "Enter the numbers correctly"

}
```

[Here the results I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLfGr.png)

Comment: The problem is read-host returns a string, not an integer.

Comment: simply cast variables `$b` and `$c` to numeric types as in `[int]$b = Read-Host "Enter a 2 digit number"`

Answer (score 3):

**[`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) always outputs a *string***.

**In order to treat its output - or any string - as a *number*, you must explicitly *convert* it to one**:

```
$a = Read-Host "What is your name?"
# Note: Add error handling with try / catch
#       and a retry loop to deal with invalid input.
[int] $b = Read-Host "Enter a 2 digit number" 
[int] $c = Read-Host "Enter a 3 digit number"
```

The above *type-constrains* variables `$b` and `$c` to integer values (by placing the `[int]` cast to the *left* of the target variable in the assignment), which automatically converts `Read-Host`'s `[string]` output to `[int]`.

This also works ad hoc with *casts*: `[int] '2' -lt 10` is `$true` (without the `[int]` cast, due to *lexical* comparison, it would be `$false`).

To spell it out with a concrete example that prompts until a two-digit (decimal) number is entered:

```
do {
  try {
    [int] $b = Read-Host "Enter a 2 digit number"
  } catch {
     continue # Not a number - stay in the loop to prompt again.
  }
  if ($b -ge 10 -and $b -le 99) { break } # OK, exit the loop.
} while ($true)
```

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, the `[int]` cast accepts anything that would work as a *number literal* in PowerShell, which includes *hexadecimal* representations, such as `0xA`, as well as number with a *type suffix*, such as `10l` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091259/45375) for more information.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

**Except for `-` (and `/`), all the operators used in your code have *string-specific* overloads (meaning)**; note that it is **sufficient for the *LHS* to be of type `[string]`** to trigger this behavior.<sup>[1]</sup>

- `-lt` / `-ge` perform *lexical* comparison with strings; e.g., `'10' -gt '2'` yields `$false`, because, in lexical sorting, string `'10'` comes before string `'2'`.
- `-and` / `-or` treat *empty* strings as `$false`, and *any nonempty* string as `$true`; e.g., 
  `'0' -and '0'` is `$true`, because `'0'` is a nonempty string.
- `+` performs *string concatenation*; e.g., `'1' + '0'` is `'10'`.
- `*` performs *string replication*; e.g., `'1' * 3` is `'111'` - the LHS is repeated as many times as specified by the number on the RHS; note that `'1' * '3'` works the same, because the RHS is coerced to an `[int]` in this case.
- `-` and `/` are the only *exceptions*: they *always* perform a numeric operation, if possible; e.g, `'10' - '2'` yields `8`, and `'10' / '2'` yields `5`, because both operands were implicitly converted to `[int]`s.

---

<sup>[1] Typically, it is the *LHS* of an operation that determines the data type of *both* operands, causing the RHS to be coerced to the same type, if necessary.</sup>