# create a typed read-only variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

Is it possible to create a typed read-only variable/constant in a PowerShell script? Afaik there a two ways to create a variable:

First way:

`[int] $myVar1`
But I am not aware of any constant / readonly keyword nor any other way to prevent changes from this variable.

Second via Cmdlet:

`New-Variable -Name 'myVar1' -Option ReadOnly` (editable with -Force) or
`New-Variable -Name 'myVar1' -Option Constant`

But I don't know any way to apply both. Any ideas?

Comment: `Set-Variable -Name 'myVar1' -Option Constant -Value <myTypedValue>`. If you create the variable `ReadOnly`, there is no way to enforce a typing constraint since the caller can always forcibly remove the variable and recreate it, so there's no real point to wanting a variable that can only be `Force`d into a particular type.

Answer (score 2):

To bring [Adam Luniewski's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60602389/45375) and [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s helpful recommendation together:

- You cannot set *variable options* as part of a *variable assignment*.

  - While you *can* apply *validation attributes* to an assignment, as shown in Adam's answer, they can't be used to enforce read-only behavior.
- Only [`New-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-variable) and [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) allow you to specify *variable options*, via their `-Option` parameter.

  - Options `ReadOnly` and `Constant` differ only by whether you can later *remove* the variable again:

    - a `ReadOnly` variable *can* be removed, with [`Remove-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-variable), if you also pass the `-Force` switch.
    - a `Constant` variable *cannot* be removed once created.

---

Therefore, to get what you want:

- Use `New-Variable` (or `Set-Variable`) with `-Option Constant`, which prevents its later removal.

  - Note that your variable can by default still be *shadowed* by a variable of the same name created in a *descendant* scope; e.g.: `Set-Variable -Option Constant var 1; & { $var = 2; $var }` - a new, local `$var` was created inside the script block, which shadowed the outer, constant one.
  - To prevent that, use `-Option Constant, AllScope`, which ensures that all code in the session sees the same value for a variable with the given name, but note that code that tries to create its own copy can then fail, so you should only do this with variable names that can be assumed not to be used for different purposes in other code.
- To assign a *specifically typed* value, pass it to `-Value` *via an expression* (enclosed in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)) - if necessary:

```
# Create a constant, [int]-typed variable.
# Note that just `-Value 42` would be sufficient here.
New-Variable -Option Constant -Name myVar1 -Value ([int] 42)
```

Just `-Value 42` would be sufficient in this case, because PowerShell by default parses unquoted arguments that can be parsed as *numbers* as such, with `[int]` as the smallest type chosen; you can even use number-type suffixes such as `L` for `[long]`. However, *negative* "number strings" (e.g., `-42`) are *not* recognized as numbers and require `(...)`.

Similarly, a *quoted* token (e.g., `'42'`) would implicitly create a `[string]`, a hashtable literal (`@{ key = 'value' }`) would create a hashtable, and so on; a simple variable reference (e.g., `$HOME`) or member access (e.g., `$HOME.ToUpper()`) would preserve the variable / member value's type.

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) provides a comprehensive overview of how unquoted token are parsed in *argument mode* (the parsing mode for commands to which arguments are passed).
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091259/45375) explains how PowerShell parses number literals (which also applies when passing unquoted tokens as command arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
New-Variable -Name x -Value ([double]5) -Option ReadOnly -Force
$x.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Double                                   System.ValueType
```

Optionally you could also use attributes to make syntax shorter:

```
[ValidateSet(2)][int]$y=2
[ValidateRange(3,3)][int]$z=3
```

But it won't throw an error if you try to assign same value again, while readonly/constant will.