# BigInt inconsistencies in PowerShell and C#

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, bigint

According to [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) the `[BigInt]` datatype seems to have no defined maximum value and theoretically can hold an infinitely large number, but I found that after the 28th digit, some weird things start to occur:

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Neko> [BigInt]9999999999999999999999999999
9999999999999999999999999999
PS C:\Users\Neko> [BigInt]99999999999999999999999999999
99999999999999991433150857216
```

As you can see, on the first command<sup>1</sup>, the `BigInt` works as intended, but with one more digit, some falloff seems to occur where it translates `99999999999999999999999999999` to `99999999999999991433150857216` however, the prompt throws no error and you can continue to add more digits until the 310th digit

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Neko> [BigInt]99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
100000000000000001097906362944045541740492309677311846336810682903157585404911491537163328978494688899061249669721172515611590283743140088328307009198146046031271664502933027185697489699588559043338384466165001178426897626212945177628091195786707458122783970171784415105291802893207873272974885715430223118336
PS C:\Users\Neko\> [BigInt]999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

which will throw the error

```powershell
At line:1 char:318
+ ... 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
+                                                                          ~
The numeric constant 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 is not valid.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadNumericConstant
```

Which I believe is a console issue rather than a `BigInt` issue because the error doesn't mention the `[BigInt]` datatype unlike numbers too big for other datatypes like

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Neko> [UInt64]18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
PS C:\Users\Neko> [UInt64]18446744073709551616
Cannot convert value "18446744073709551616" to type "System.UInt64". Error: "Value was either too large or too small
for a UInt64."
At line:1 char:1
+ [UInt64]18446744073709551616
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible
```

As for C#, `System.Numerics.BigInt` will start throwing an error at the 20th digit, `99999999999999999999` when hard coded:

```C#
namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            System.Numerics.BigInteger TestInput;
            System.Numerics.BigInteger Test = 99999999999999999999;
            System.Console.WriteLine(Test);
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to build in Visual Studio I get the error

```
Integral constant is too large
```

However, I can enter a bigger number to `ReadLine` without causing an error

```C#
namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            System.Numerics.BigInteger TestInput;
            TestInput = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
            System.Console.WriteLine(TestInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Which seems to indeed be infinite. The input

```
99999999999...
```

(24720 characters total) works fine<sup>2</sup>

So what is causing all of this weird activity with `[BigInt]`?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>which is 28 digits according to `([Char[]]"$([BigInt]9999999999999999999999999999)").count`</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>I am too lazy to count the digits and trying to parse the digits into PowerShell causes an error. According to [this](https://www.lettercount.com/) it is 24720 characters</sub>

Comment: What I would like to know (in addition) is why `[BigInt]'99999999999999999999999999999'` (shorthand for `[BigInt]::New('99999999999999999999999999999')`, ***which doesn't work*** and isn't mentioned as a workaround in any of the answers - *yet*) works fine (in PowerShell Core 7). Especially knowing that the `[BigInt]` type doesn't have any constructors that accept a string (see: `[BigInt]::new`) for input.

Comment: @iRon I've addressed this in an update.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**TLDR**: Use `[BigInt]::Parse` or `'literal'` syntax prior to Powershell Core 7.0; otherwise use the `n` suffix.

## The Problem - `double` literals

When it comes to un-suffixed literals, Powershell will use the first type the value fits in. The order for *integral* literals is `int`, `long`, `decimal` and then `double`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-5.1) for Powershell 5.1 (bolding mine; this paragraph is the same for Powershell Core):

> For an integer literal with no type suffix:
>
> - If the value can be represented by type `[int]`, that is its type.
> - Otherwise, if the value can be represented by type `[long]`, that is its type.
> - Otherwise, if the value can be represented by type `[decimal]`, that is its type.
> - **Otherwise, it is represented by type `[double]`**.

In your case the value exceeds that of `decimal.MaxValue` so your literal is by default a `double` literal. That `double` value is not exactly representable and is "converted" to the closest *representable* double.

```
$h = [double]99999999999999999999999999999
"{0:G29}" -f $h
```

Outputs

```
99999999999999991000000000000
```

Obviously that's not the *exact* number, just a representation in string form. But it gives you an idea what's going on. Now we take this *inexact* `double` value and we *cast* it to `BigInt`. The original loss in precision is transferred over and compounded upon by the *conversion operator*. This is what is *actually* happening in Powershell (note the cast to `BigInt`):

```
$h = [BigInt][double]99999999999999999999999999999
"{0:G}" -f $h
```

Outputs

```
99999999999999991433150857216
```

This is in fact the closest representable `double` value. If you could [print the exact value](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) of the `double` from the first example, this is what it would print. When you add the additional extra digits, you exceed the largest value of a **numeric literal,** thus the other exception you received.

## C# Inconsistencies

Unlike Powershell, C# uses **integral literals** by default which is why you get the exception for a lot fewer digits. Adding the `D` suffix in C# will give you a larger range. The following works fine and will be a `double`.

```
var h = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999D;
```

Adding one more digit will raise the following error:

> error CS0594: Floating-point constant is outside the range of type 'double'

Note that in Powershell the `D` suffix is used  for `decimal` literals and *not* `double`. There is not an explicit suffix for `double`--it is assumed to be the default.

## Solutions

Back to your original problem, depending on your Powershell version the solution may vary:

### `[BigInt]::Parse`

If you are using Windows Powershell or Powershell Core <= v6.2, one option is to use `BigInteger.Parse`:

```
[bigint]::Parse("99999999999999999999999999999")
```

Outputs:

```
99999999999999999999999999999
```

### Large Value Literals

As pointed out in the comments, another option that works is to enclose the literal in quotes.

```
[bigint]'99999999999999999999999999999'
```

Outputs

```
99999999999999999999999999999
```

Despite how it looks, this is **not** shorthand for `[bigint]::new([string])` (see below). This is instead a way to ensure that the literal is not treated as a `double` but rather as an integral literal with many digits, a so-called "large value literal". See [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7#parsing-large-value-literals) of the docs.

### `N` Integral Suffix (v7.0+)

Powershell Core 6.2 introduced many new literal suffixes for integral types such as unsigned, `short`, and `byte` but did not introduce one for `bigint`. That came along in Powershell Core 7.0 via the `n` suffix. This means you can now do the following:

```
99999999999999999999999999999n
```

Outputs:

```
99999999999999999999999999999
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7) for more information on the suffixes available in Powershell Core.

## `[BigInt]::new`

If you were to try `[bigint]::new('literal')` Powershell recognizes that you intend to use the value as a *literal*. There is in fact no constructor for `BigInt` that accepts a `string` (we use `Parse` for that) nor is there a constructor which accepts another `BigInt`. There is however a constructor that takes a `double`. Our large-value literal will start as a `BigInt`, Powershell will then implicitly convert that to a `double` (losing precision) and then pass it to `[bigint]::new([double])` as the best match, once again giving an incorrect result:

```
[bigint]::new('99999999999999999999999999999')
```

Outputs:

```
99999999999999991433150857216
```

Comment: PowerShell v7.0 changed the way numeric literals are parsed to enable the new features.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately C# have not literal for BigInteger. There are two ways to instantiate BigInteger:

1. Convert from primitive type like int, long (cast or using constructor)
2. Parse from string using BigInteger.Parse

---

```
BigInteger test = BigInteger.Parse("32439845934875938475398457938457389475983475893475389457839475");
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
// output: 32439845934875938475398457938457389475983475893475389457839475
```

See [How PowerShell parses numeric literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7#how-powershell-parses-numeric-literals)

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear but this does help answer the question but doesn't fully answer the question. I am looking for the causes of the weird activity in PowerShell and inconsistencies between C# and PowerShell

Comment: This is due to differences in languages. See how powershell parses numeric literals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7)

Comment: the biggest integer literal in C# (decimal type) is
decimal m = 79_228_162_514_264_337_593_543_950_335m;

Answer (score 9):

To complement the existing, helpful answers - notably [pinkfloydx33's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62974358/45375) - with a **succinct summary**:

By default, all PowerShell versions up to at least v7.0 use **`[double]` as the data type for *number literals* that are *larger than `[decimal]::MaxValue`***, which **invariably leads to a *loss of accuracy***.

- **Up to v6.x** (which includes *Windows PowerShell*), the only way to avoid this is to **use `[bigint]::Parse()` with the number represented as a *string***:

```
[bigint]::Parse('99999999999999999999999999999')

# A *cast* works too, as also shown in pinkfloydx33's answer:
[bigint] '99999999999999999999999999999'
```

- **In v7+**, you can use the **`n` suffix** to designate a number literal as a `[bigint]`:

```
99999999999999999999999999999n  # v7+; parses as a [bigint], due to suffix 'n'
```

Note: Arguably, given that PowerShell usually *automatically* picks an appropriate number type, it should *assume* `n` in this case, i.e. it should parse unsuffixed `99999999999999999999999999999` as a `[bigint]`, not as a `[double]` - see [this GitHub proposal](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13212).

---

Further reading:

- See [about_Numeric_Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals), which shows all number-type suffixes, including what PowerShell version they were introduced in.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091259/45375) summarizes how number literals are interpreted in PowerShell.

  - In short: For *integer* literals, `[int]` is the smallest type ever chosen, with `[long]` or `[decimal]` chosen as needed to accommodate larger values, with `[double]` used for values beyond `[decimal]::MaxValue`.

Answer (score 1):

A little more information coming at this from a metadata perspective,

PowerShell and C# will both use the same module in `.NET Core` to get the `BigInt` datatype, and you can view the metadata for the `BigInteger` struct in

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
```

This includes the constructors for

```
public BigInteger(byte[] value);
public BigInteger(decimal value);
public BigInteger(double value);
public BigInteger(int value);
public BigInteger(long value);
public BigInteger(float value);
public BigInteger(uint value);
public BigInteger(ulong value);
public BigInteger(ReadOnlySpan<byte> value, bool isUnsigned = false, bool isBigEndian = false);
```

Which means the base

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger test = 12345;
```

Will inadvertently attempt to convert the value passed to the constructor into one of these datatypes which the highest value it could take, the maximum value of `double`, however C# will **not try to convert a number to double unless specified with the `D` suffix** so the max value that doesn't need a suffix would be `ULong` which has the max value of `18446744073709551615` (According to `ULong.MaxValue`) which happens to be less than `99999999999999999999`, the number that caused the integral constant error, but greater than `9999999999999999999`, one character less. This is why simply doing

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger test = 99999999999999999999;
```

will have an error. However, the `Parse()` method in `BigInteger` can take values *other* than the integer types from the constructor, it take strings:

```
public static BigInteger Parse(ReadOnlySpan<char> value, NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Integer, IFormatProvider provider = null);
public static BigInteger Parse(string value);
public static BigInteger Parse(string value, NumberStyles style);
public static BigInteger Parse(string value, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider);
public static BigInteger Parse(string value, IFormatProvider provider);
```

As you can see, the `Parse()` method for `System.Numerics.BigInteger` will take *string* arguments which have no limits since they aren't integers but words. This is why the `Parse()` method indeed **will** give you unlimited value space.

As for PowerShell, like in other answers say, ***anything past the `[decimal]` max value will attempt to get converted to the `[double]` datatype which has many inaccuracies*** and the `[double]` datatype's max value *is* 309 digits and that is why errors only show up after the 309th digit.

```
[double]::MaxValue
1.79769313486232E+308
```

To convert this to normal value not in scientific notation, we will move the decimal point over 308 times resulting in about

```
179769313486232000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

being the highest possible double. The `[double] datatype in PowerShell also has very strange properties that are also very inaccurate like

```
[BigInt][double]9999999999999999999999
10000000000000000000000
[BigInt][double]9999999999999999999999999
10000000000000000905969664
[double]9999999999999999999
1E+19
```

Since PowerShell gets the `BigInt` type also from the same struct as C#, the methods and constructors are the same and `Parse()` will also work the same way in PowerShell as it does in C#. There were changes in PowerShell 7 allowing the `N` suffix to automatically be converted directly to `BigInt`.

`BigInt` also doesn't use scientific notation so it always will get the exact value if another datatype in used so to to get the exact value you could use

```
[BigInt]([double]::MaxValue)
```

Which will get you

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

being the highest possible double.

---

#### Commands that you want

PowerShell 6.x and below

```
[BigInt]::Parse("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999")
```

PowerShell 7.0 and above

```
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999N
```

C#

```
System.Numerics.Biginteger test = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999")
```