# In PowerShell, why is $null -lt 0 = $true? Is that reliable?

Tags: powershell, null

Consider the following PowerShell code:

```
> $null -gt 0
False
> $null -ge 0
False
> $null -eq 0
False
> $null -le 0
True
> $null -lt 0
True
```

Of course the same is true for a $variable explicitly set to `$null` or for a non-existent variable.

1. Why is that? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. I feel like $null by definition doesn't have a value that could be tested as such, or at the very least, that it would evaluate to zero in such tests. But other than that I guess I don't know what behavior I would actually expect. Googling (or searching SO) for e.g. "Why is null less than zero in Powershell" doesn't seem to yield any results, though I do see relevant questions and answers for several other languages.
2. Can and *should* this result be relied on?
3. Aside from testing the variable with GetType(), or various implementations of "IsNumeric", "IsNullOrEmpty", etc. what is a the best (i.e. most concise, best performing, etc.) way to reliably test for integer values (or other types for that matter) in a variable that might have a value of `$null`? Or is one of those methods considered pretty standard?

Thanks for your time. Apologies in advance if this is too "squishy" of a question for this venue.

P.S. For what it's worth my usual environment is PowerShell v5.1.

Comment: Most reliable way to check integer values would be to check the type the following way ```$var -is [int] -and $var -lt 0```

Comment: If you think it's confusing in Powershell, you should see SQL!

Comment: Yeah, I... did not expect it to be that complicated either /shrug

Comment: In many programming languages and runtimes, "null" comes before anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is that?

The **behavior is counterintuitive**:

**Operators `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, `-ge`, even though they can *also* have *numeric* meaning, seemingly treat a `$null` operand as if it were *the empty string* (`''`), i.e. they default to *string comparison***, as the sample commands in [postanote's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397251/45375) imply.

That is, **`$null -lt 0` is in effect evaluated the same as `'' -lt '0'`**, which explains the `$true` result, because in *lexical* comparison the condition is met.
While you can conceive of `$null -eq 0` as `'' -eq '0'` too, **the `-eq` case is special** - see below.

Additionally, **placing the `0` on the *LHS* still acts like a string comparison (except with `-eq` see below) - even though it is normally the type of the LHS that causes the RHS to be coerced to the same type**.

That is, **`0 -le $null` too seems to act like `'0' -le ''`** and therefore returns `$false`.

**While such behavior is to be expected in operators that are *exclusively* string-based, such as `-match` and `-like`, it is surprising for operators that *also support numbers***, especially given that **other such operators - as well as those that are *exclusively* numeric - default to *numeric* interpretation of `$null`, as `0`**.

- `+`, `-`, and `/` *do* force a LHS `$null` to `0` (`[int]` by default); e.g. `$null + 0` is `0`
- `*` does *not*; e.g., `$null * 0` is again `$null`.

Of these, `-` and `/` are *exclusively* numeric, whereas `+` and `*` also work in *string* and *array* contexts.

There is an **additional inconsistency: `-eq` *never* performs type coercion on a `$null` operand**:

- **`$null -eq <RHS>` is only ever `$true` if `<RHS>` is also `$null`** (or "automation null" - see below), and is currently **the only way to reliably test a value for being `$null`**. (To put it differently: `$null -eq ''` is *not* the same as `'' -eq ''` - *no type coercion takes place here*.)

  - [GitHub PR #10704](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10704), which has unfortunately stalled, aims to implement a dedicated syntax for `$null` tests, such as `<LHS> -is $null`.
- Similarly, **`<LHS> -eq $null`** also performs no type coercion on `$null` and returns `$true` only with `$null` as the LHS;

  - However, **with an *array*-valued `<LHS>`, `-eq` acts as *filter*** (as most operators do), returning the *subarray of elements that are `$null`*; e.g., `1, $null, 2, $null, 3 -eq $null` returs 2-element array `$null, $null`.
  - This filtering behavior is the reason that only `$null -eq <RHS>` - with `$null` as the scalar LHS - is reliable as a test for (scalar) `$null`.

Note that the **behaviors equally apply to the "automation null" value** that PowerShell uses to express the (non-)output from *commands* (technically, the [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value)), because this value is treated the same as `$null` in *expressions*; e.g. `$(& {}) -lt 0` is also `$true` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41568525/45375) for more information.

Similarly, the behaviors also apply to instances of *nullable value types* that happen to contain `$null` (e.g., `[System.Nullable[int]] $x = $null; $x -lt 0` is also `$true`)<sup>Thanks, [Dávid Laczkó](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10644878/d%c3%a1vid-laczk%c3%b3).</sup>, though note that their use in PowerShell is rare.

---

> Can and should this result be relied on?

Since the behavior is inconsistent across operators, **I wouldn't rely on it**, not least because it's also hard to remember which rules apply when - and there's at least a hypothetical chance that the inconsistency will be fixed; given that this would amount to a *breaking* change, however, that may not happen.

**If backward compatibility *weren't* a concern, the following behavior would remove the inconsistencies and make for rules that are easy to conceptualize and remember**:

When a (fundamentally scalar) binary operator is given a `$null` operand as well as a non-`$null` operand - irrespective of which is the LHS and which is the RHS:

- For operators that operate *exclusively* on numeric / Boolean / string operands (e.g. `/` / `-and` / `-match`): coerce the `$null` operand to the type implied by the operator.
- For operators that operate in *multiple* "domains" - both textual and numeric (e.g. `-eq`) - coerce the `$null` operand to the *other* operand's type.

Note that this would then additionally require a dedicated `$null` test with different syntax, such as the `-is $null` from the above-mentioned PR.

Note: The above does *not* apply to the *collection* operators, `-in` and `-contains` (and their negated variants `-notin` and `-notcontains`), because their element-wise equality comparison acts like `-eq` and therefore never applies type coercion to `$null` values.

---

> what is the best (i.e. most concise, best performing, etc.) way to **reliably test for integer values (or other types for that matter)** in a variable that might have a value of $null?

**The following solutions force a `$null` operand to `0`**:

- Note: `(...)` around the LHS of the `-lt` operations below is used for conceptual clarity, but isn't strictly necessary - see [about_Operator_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence).

In **PowerShell (Core) 7+**, use **`??`**, the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-operator-), which works with operands of *any* type:

```
# PowerShell 7+ only
($null ?? 0) -lt 0 # -> $false
```

In **Windows PowerShell**, where this operator isn't supported, **use a dummy calculation**:

```
# Windows PowerShell
(0 + $null) -lt 0  # -> $false
```

While something like `[int] $null -lt 0` works too, it requires you to commit to a *specific* numeric type, so if the operand happens to be higher than `[int]::MaxValue`, the expression will fail; `[double] $null -lt 0` would minimize that risk, though could at least hypothetically result in loss of accuracy.

The **dummy addition** (`0 +`) bypasses this problem and **lets PowerShell apply its usual *on-demand type-widening***.

As an aside: This **automatic type-widening can exhibit unexpected behavior too, because an all-integer calculation whose result requires a wider type than either operand's type can fit is always widened to `[double]`, even when a larger *integer* type would suffice**; e.g. `([int]::MaxValue + 1).GetType().Name` returns `Double`, even though a `[long]` result would have sufficed, resulting in potential loss of accuracy - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091259/45375) for more information.

Comment: @mmseng, unfortunately, I wasn't done yet: `0 -le $null` returning `$false` is another head scratcher, given that the LHS type usually causes the RHS to be coerced to it - but this too behaves like `'0' -le ''`. It's a good question whether string comparison is actually used (I haven't tried to dig into the source code), but in a sense the question is academic, because _de facto_ it behaves like that, in the cases described. I've also overhauled the section about how things _should_ work, if backward compatibility weren't in the picture. The bottom line is: `$null` is special - way too special

Comment: Thanks, @DávidLaczkó, I've added a note to the answer. Yes, nullable value-type instances that happen to contain `$null` behave just like `$null`, in both PowerShell editions.

Answer (score 2):

Test $null comparison results

```
(0).GetType()
('').GetType()
(' ').GetType()
($null).GetType()
# Results
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     String                                   System.Object
True     True     String                                   System.Object
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
#>

Measure-Object -InputObject (0).GetType()
Measure-Object -InputObject ('').GetType()
Measure-Object -InputObject (' ').GetType()
Measure-Object -InputObject ($null).GetType()
# Results
<#
Count    : 1
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

Count    : 1
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

Count    : 1
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
#>


$Null -eq '' 
[string]$Null -eq ''
$Null -eq [string]''
[string]$Null -eq [string]''
# Results
<#
False
True
False
True
#>

$Null -eq '' 
[bool]$Null -eq ''
$Null -eq [bool]''
[bool]$Null -eq [bool]''
# Results
<#
False
True
False
True
#>


$Null -eq '' 
[int]$Null -eq ''
$Null -eq [int]''
[int]$Null -eq [int]''
# Results
<#
False
True
False
True
#>


$Null -eq '' 
[double]$Null -eq ''
$Null -eq [double]''
[double]$Null -eq [double]''
# Results
<#
False
True
False
True
#>



Clear-Host 
0, $null | 
ForEach {
    ('#')*40
    "`nTest `$null as default"
    $null -gt $PSItem
    $null -ge $PSItem
    $null -eq $PSItem
    $null -le $PSItem
    $null -lt $PSItem


    "`n"
    ('#')*40
    "Using $PSItem"
    "`nTest `$null as string"
    "Left Side`tRight Side`tBoth Sides"
    Write-Host ([string]$null -gt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -gt [string]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([string]$null -gt [string]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([string]$null -ge $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -ge [string]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([string]$null -ge [string]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([string]$null -eq $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -eq [string]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([string]$null -eq [string]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([string]$null -le $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -le [string]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([string]$null -le [string]$PSItem)


    Write-Host ([string]$null -lt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -lt [string]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([string]$null -lt [string]$PSItem)


    "`n"
    ('#')*40
    "Using $PSItem"
    "`nTest `$null as boolean"
    "Left Side`tRight Side`tBoth Sides"
    Write-Host ([boolean]$null -gt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -gt [boolean]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([boolean]$null -gt [boolean]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([boolean]$null -ge $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -ge [boolean]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([boolean]$null -ge [boolean]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([boolean]$null -eq $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -eq [boolean]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([boolean]$null -eq [boolean]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([boolean]$null -le $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -le [boolean]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([boolean]$null -le [boolean]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([boolean]$null -lt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -lt [boolean]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([boolean]$null -lt [boolean]$PSItem)


    "`n"
    ('#')*40
    "Using $PSItem"
    "`nTest `$null as int"
    "Left Side`tRight Side`tBoth Sides"
    Write-Host ([int]$null -gt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -gt [int]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([int]$null -gt [int]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([int]$null -ge $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -ge [int]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([int]$null -ge [int]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([int]$null -eq $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -eq [int]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([int]$null -eq [int]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([int]$null -le $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -le [int]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([int]$null -le [int]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([int]$null -lt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -lt [int]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([int]$null -lt [int]$PSItem)


    "`n"
    ('#')*40
    "Using $PSItem"
    "`nTest `$null as double"
    "Left Side`tRight Side`tBoth Sides"
    Write-Host ([double]$null -gt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -gt [double]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([double]$null -gt [double]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([double]$null -ge $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -ge [double]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([double]$null -ge [double]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([double]$null -eq $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -eq [double]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([double]$null -eq [double]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([double]$null -le $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -le [double]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([double]$null -le [double]$PSItem)

    Write-Host ([double]$null -lt $PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ($null -lt [double]$PSItem) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t|`t" ([double]$null -lt [double]$PSItem)
}
# Results
<#
########################################

Test $null as default
False
False
False
True
True


########################################
Using 0

Test $null as string
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
False   |    False  |    False
False   |    False  |    False
False   |    False  |    False
True    |    True   |    True
True    |    True   |    True


########################################
Using 0

Test $null as boolean
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
False   |    False  |    False
True    |    False  |    True
True    |    False  |    True
True    |    True   |    True
False   |    True   |    False


########################################
Using 0

Test $null as int
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
False   |    False  |    False
True    |    False  |    True
True    |    False  |    True
True    |    True   |    True
False   |    True   |    False


########################################
Using 0

Test $null as double
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
False   |    False  |    False
True    |    False  |    True
True    |    False  |    True
True    |    True   |    True
False   |    True   |    False
########################################

Test $null as default
False
True
True
True
False


########################################
Using 

Test $null as string
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
True    |    False  |    False
True    |    False  |    True
False   |    False  |    True
False   |    True   |    True
False   |    True   |    False


########################################
Using 

Test $null as boolean
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
True    |    False  |    False
True    |    False  |    True
False   |    False  |    True
False   |    True   |    True
False   |    True   |    False


########################################
Using 

Test $null as int
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
True    |    False  |    False
True    |    False  |    True
False   |    False  |    True
False   |    True   |    True
False   |    True   |    False


########################################
Using 

Test $null as double
Left Side   Right Side  Both Sides
True    |    False  |    False
True    |    False  |    True
False   |    False  |    True
False   |    True   |    True
False   |    True   |    False
#>
```

Comment: It might point in the right direction, but it is not a founded answer. Does this mean that the the left side defaults to a `string` type if it is `$Null`? (apparently not as this `$Null -eq ''` returns `False` and this `[string]$Null -eq ''` returns `True`). Normally comparison is done based on the type of the left side value, in case that is `$Null` (no left side *type*), I would expect that the comparison is done based on the type of the right side value.

Comment: Yet the OP is talking about, `0`, not `''`. If `0` is the use case then, if you do the cast the same on both sides, the result is the same as shown. If you cast only on the right then the results are the as shown in the default or string. Taking you are your point, then `(0).GetType() = Int32, ('').GetType() = String, ($null).GetType() = You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` and `$Null -eq '' = False, [string]$Null -eq '' = True, $Null -eq [string]'' = False, [string]$Null -eq [string]'' = True`

Comment: That is interesting, that the results mirror the string-casted results. It does raise the question of exactly what type is being used as a basis for the comparison, and how that type is being decided upon.

Comment: Yeppers, this `$null`, `''`, `0` comparison thing comes up a lot across multiple Q&A, forum,. blog sites.