# Powershell - If Statement Output 2 values

Tags: powershell, if-statement, vmware, esx

Iam trying to write a script to notify if a VMware VM Custom attribute has a value or if the value is null.
I need the VM name and the Output Value (either Null or Not Null). Here is what I have but doesn't return the accurate information

```
$vms = Get-VM

foreach ($vm in $vms) {

    $tag = $vm | Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute "Backup"
   
    if ($tag.value -eq '$null'){
        Write-Output "$vm Attribute doesnt have a value"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "$vm Attribute has a value assigned"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're specifically looking for the literal string value `'$null'`, you probably want to change the comparison to `$null -eq $tag.value`

You could create a new object with 2 properties:

```
$vms = Get-VM

foreach ($vm in $vms) {

    $tag = $vm | Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute "Backup"
   
    if ($null -eq $tag.value){
        $result = "$vm Attribute doesnt have a value"
    }
    else {
        $result = Write-Output "$vm Attribute has a value assigned"
    }

    # output object with Name + result
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $vm.Name
        Result = $result
    }
}
```

Another, perhaps more PowerShell-idiomatic approach would be to create a similar object with the `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-VM |Select-Object Name,@{Name='HasBackupAttribute';Expression={ $null -eq ($_ | Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute "Backup").Value }}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias but this does not work. The output is lisiting every vm with "Attribute has a value assigned "    At least half of them do not have a value assigned

Answer (score 0):

When looking at dealing with $null comparisons, see this SO Q&A:
[In PowerShell, why is $null -lt 0 = $true? Is that reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396721/in-powershell-why-is-null-lt-0-true-is-that-reliable/66397251#66397251)

I do not have VMware at the moment, but in my small Hyper-V lab, running the following delivers the shown results:

```
Try
{
    (
        Get-VM | 
        Where-Object -Property FloppyDrive -eq $null | 
        Select Name, FloppyDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ).Count
}
Catch { Write-Warning -Message 'No no records returned'}
# Results
<#
4
#>

Try
{
    (
        Get-VM | 
        Where-Object -Property FloppyDrive -ne $null | 
        Select Name, FloppyDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ).Count
}
Catch { Write-Warning -Message 'No no records returned'}
# Results
<#
WARNING: No no records returned
#>
```

The results are the same using these as well.

```
Try
{
    (
        Get-VM | 
        Where-Object -Property FloppyDrive -Match $null | 
        Select Name, FloppyDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ).Count
}
Catch { Write-Warning -Message 'No no records returned'}

Try
{
    (
        Get-VM | 
        Where-Object -Property FloppyDrive -NotMatch $null | 
        Select Name, FloppyDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ).Count
}
Catch { Write-Warning -Message 'No no records returned'}
```

In your use case, try this refactor:

```
(Get-VM).Name | 
foreach {
    if ((Get-VM -Entity $PSitem | Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute 'Backup') -eq $null)
    { "$PSItem - Attribute doesnt have a value"    }
    else {"$PSItem - Attribute has a value assigned"}
}
```

Or...

```
    (Get-VM).Name | 
foreach {
    if ((Get-VM -Entity $PSitem | Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute 'Backup') -Match $null)
    { "$PSItem - Attribute doesnt have a value"    }
    else {"$PSItem - Attribute has a value assigned"}
}
```

Comment: Hii, I've tried running but they both throw the following exception

Get-VM : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Entity'.
At line:3 char:24
+     if ((Get-VM -Entity <<<<  $PSitem | Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute 'Backup') -eq $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-VM], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetVM

Comment: Remove the `-Entity`. Again I don't have VMware as part of my lab, so, I went to the VMWare docs, for the command. https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6bd6daa3-08a8-4660-9159-23265b9d6c00/4d533cf0-f009-4fa0-8679-8d505fbe846b/doc/Get-Annotation.html

Answer (score 0):

Annotation values are strings. When there is no value present, the string is considered empty rather than null. So the `$null -eq value` test will not yield the desired results. You can simply perform an implicit boolean conversion of the value to determine if it is empty.

```
$vms = Get-VM
foreach ($vm in $vms) {

    $tag = $vm | Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute "Backup"
    # Empty string returns false. Nonempty string returns true.
    if ($tag.value){
        Write-Output "$vm Attribute has a value assigned"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "$vm Attribute doesn't have a value"
    }
}
```

---

You will discover that `$tag.value | Get-Member` returns a type `System.String`. So when `value` seemingly has no value, it actually is an empty string. You can perform a variety of tests to determine if the value is empty. An empty string value inside of an `if` statement evaluates to `False`. See below for some examples, which can all be used inside of `if` statements.

```
$Empty = [pscustomobject]@{value = ''}
$NotEmpty = [pscustomobject]@{value = 'My String'}

# Test 1 Using IsNullOrEmpty static method
[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Empty.value)
True
[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NotEmpty.value)
False

# Test 2 Using [bool] type accelerator
[bool]$Empty.value
False
[bool]$NotEmpty.value
True

# Test 3 Using length property. Empty string has length of 0.
$Empty.value.length -eq 0
True
$NotEmpty.value.length -eq 0
False

# Test 4 Using if statement. ! in front of an expression negates its boolean value
if ($Empty.value) { "Value is not empty" } else { "Value is empty" }
Value is empty
if ($NotEmpty.value) { "Value is not empty" } else { "Value is empty" }
Value is not empty
if (!$Empty.value) { "Value is empty" }
Value is empty
```