# Why can't I dot-reference a hashtable key's value property if the property name is an integer

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Consider the following hashtable:

```
$table = @{
  6           = '10.11.12.13', '10.11.12.14'
  15          = 'domain.tld'
  NameServers = '10.11.12.13', '10.11.12.14'
}
```

Normally when you have a hashtable, you can `.` reference the key name to work with it in a more object-oriented style vs. using the array-accessor syntax `[key]`. For example, invoking the `NameServers` key on the hashtable above with a `.` results in the value being returned, and I can work with members of that property's value as expected:

```
$table.NameServers       # ========> 10.11.12.13
                         # ========> 10.11.12.14

$table.NameServers.Count # ========> 2
```

But if I try accessing the `6` key with a `.` which contains the same string content, it references the correct value fine, but I cannot invoke any members on the returned object. I *must* use the traditional array-accessor here:

```
$table.6        # =====> 10.11.12.13
                # =====> 10.11.12.14

$table.6.Count  # =====> ParserError:
                # =====> Line |
                # =====>    1 |  $hi.6.Count
                # =====>      |      ~
                # =====>      | Missing property name after reference operator.

$table[6].Count # =====> 2
```

Of course, `( $table.6 ).Count` works around this issue but this is still a weird quirk of the syntax which I can't explain. Interestingly enough, converting the hashtable to a `PSCustomObject` yields the same issue. Is this perhaps a parser bug? Or is there something else going on here?

I tested this in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7.1 and it happens in both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Note: This answer originally incorrectly claimed that `$table.6` doesn't work, due to the hashtable key being *integer*-typed, but it works just fine, because the `6` in the `.6` "property" access is parsed as an integer as well.</sup>

As [Gyula Kokas' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68763449/45375) points out, **you're seeing problematic behavior in PowerShell's parser**, present as of PowerShell 7.2, discussed in detail in [GitHub issue #14036](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14036). The behavior is **unrelated to [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) *per se***:

- What follows `.`, the member-access operator, is parsed *as a number* if it looks like a *number literal*, such as `6`, `6l` (a `[long]`) or even `6.0`(!, a `[double]`).

  - See below for how that number is then *used*.
- Any attempt to use *another* property access then triggers the error you saw:

  ```
  $foo.6.bar # !! Error "Missing property name after reference operator."
  ```

  - In fact, following a property name that *starts with a digit* with a *letter* causes the error too - even though `6a` can *not* interpreted as a number literal.

    ```
    $foo.6a # !! Same error.
    ```

As an aside: PowerShell even allows you to use *variable* references, and even *expressions* (enclosed in `(...)`) as property names (e.g., `$propName = 'Length'; 'foo'.$propName` or (`'foo'.('L' + 'ength')`

**Workarounds**:

- As you've demonstrated, enclosing the first property access in `(...)` - `($table.6).Count` works, and so does `$table.(6).Count`
- You've also demonstrated `$table[6].Count`, which works for *hashtables*.
- For accessing an object's actual *property*, `$obj.'6'.Count` would work too (given that property names are always *strings*), as it would with hashtables with *string* keys (e.g. `@{ '6'= 'six' }.'6'.Length`)

---

**Considerations specific to *hashtables*:**

**As a *syntactic convenience*, PowerShell allows *property*-access syntax (`$obj.someProperty`) to also be used to access the *entries* of a hashtable**, in which case the property "name" is taken as the *key* of an entry in the hashtable.

The **type-native syntax to access hashtable entries is *index syntax* (`$hash[$someKey]`)**.

While *property names* (referring to *members* of a .NET type) are invariably *strings*:

- **a hashtable's *keys* can be of *any type***.
- on *accessing* an entry, the **lookup key** must not only have the right *value*, but must also be of the ***exact same type* as the key stored in the hashtable**.

Perhaps surprisingly, **when *defining* a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), *unquoted* keys *situationally* become either *strings* or *numbers***:

- If the unquoted word *can* be interpreted as a *number literal* (e.g., `6`), it is parsed as such, and you end up with a *numeric* key; in the case of `6`, it will be `[int]`-typed key, because the usual number-literal typing applies (e.g., `1.0` would become a `[double]` key (not advisable, because *binary* floating-point values do not always have exact *decimal* representations), and `2147483648` would become a `[long]`).
- Otherwise (e.g., `NameServers`), the key is `[string]`-typed.

  - Caveat: If the name *starts with a digit* (but isn't a number literal; e.g. `6a`), an *error* occurs; use quoting (`'6a'`) as a workaround - see [GitHub issue #15925](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15925)

That is, even though strings in expressions normally require *quoting*, for convenience you may omit the quoting when defining keys in hashtable literals - but the rules for recognizing *number literals* still apply.

***Explicitly typing* hashtable keys:**

- **To *ensure* that a given key is interpreted as a `[string]`, *quote* it (e.g., `'6'`)**
- Generally, you may also use a *cast* to type your keys explicitly. (e.g. `[long] 6`) or, in number literals, the usual *number-type suffix characters*, such as `L` for `[long]` (e.g. `6L`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091259/45375) for an overview of the supported suffixes, whose number has grown significantly in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

An **example**, based on your hashtable:

It follows from the above that your `6` key is of type `[int]` (and would have to be defined as `'6'` in your hashtable literal if you wanted it to be a *string*).

Because the `6` in `$name.6` is *also* parsed as an `[int]`, the lookup succeeds, but note that it wouldn't succeed if *different numeric types* were at play:

```
# !! Output is $null, because the entry key is of type [long], 
# !! whereas the lookup key is [int].
@{ 6L = '[long] 6' }.6
```

---

**Considerations specific to *property* access**:

With actual *property* access (accessing a native member of a .NET type), **the fact that names that *look like numbers* are actually parsed as numbers *first* - before, of necessity, being converted to *strings* - can result in surprising behavior**:

```
# !! Output is $null, because the 6L after "." is parsed as a 
# !! ([long]) number first, and then converted to a string, which
# !! results in "6" being used.
([pscustomobject] @{ '6L' = 'foo' }).6L

# OK - The quoting forces 6L to be a string.
([pscustomobject] @{ '6L' = 'foo' }).'6L' # -> 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think here is the official issue for your question:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14036

I think the best workaround is $table.(6).count

Answer (score 2):

Hashtables in powershell expect key names to be strings.  When you type $table.6 based on your original code the 6 is interpreted as an integer when it's expecting it to be a string (a type conversion feature).  The simplest way to resolve this would be to replace 6 with 'six', however you can make this work in a round about way.

If you make the alterations to the code like so:

```
$table = @{
  '6' = '10.11.12.13', '10.11.12.14'
  '15' = 'domain.tld'
  NameServers = '10.11.12.13', '10.11.12.14'
}
```

You can reference it by implicitly instructing powershell to treat the 6 as a string by doing the following:

```
$table.'6'.count
2
```

It's the same principal as adding keynames with special characters, they have to be instantiated as strings to prevent interpolation or type conversion.  For example:

```
$table = @{'bla $something' = 'anything'}
$table.'bla $something'
anything
```

In your case I'd do the following and move on to the next problem:

```
$table = @{
  Six = '10.11.12.13', '10.11.12.14'
  Fifteen = 'domain.tld'
  NameServers = '10.11.12.13', '10.11.12.14'
}

$table.Six.count
2
```

For further investigation into type conversion follow this link: [Powershell Type Conversion Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: While explicitly defining the hashtable keys as strings is an option, note that _powershell expect key names to be strings is not correct_ - you can use objects of any type as keys. You are correct about the `6` in `.6` being interpreted as an integer (unlike what I claimed earlier - my apologies),
but so is the key if defined _unquoted_, e.g.. `@{ 6 = 'six' }.6` works just fine. Generally, note that _no_ type conversions are involved in hashtable key lookups. The OP's problem is ultimately unrelated to hashtables and is a general _parser bug_.