# How can I access Powershell PSCustomObject properties?

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I'm processing through Powershell script some API result processing.
API data (json) come from this :

```
$tree = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "xxxxxxxxmonURLxxxxxxxxxx/130333"  
$children = ($tree.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).data.12345.children
```

Then I loop through $children object using  `| ForEach`
`$_` within loop has "147852" as `$_.Name`, and the following object as `$_.Definition`
I'd like to parse the object within `$_.Definition` but cannot figure out how to access it.

The Definition object looks like this:

```
  TypeName : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
 
Name   MemberType   Definition
----   ----------   ----------
147852 NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject 147852=@{nodeType=node; name=test1; flag=N0; creationDate=2022-02-17T14:50:16+00:00; hasAlerts=False; children=}
```

And I wish to access any property within the `147852` key (such as nodeType, name, flag, ..., children).

$_.147852 outputs an error saying `147852` was not found.

Thanks.

API json returned:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "130333": {
            "nodeType": "node",
            "name": "Test name",
            "flag": "N0",
            "children": {
                "147852": {
                    "nodeType": "node",
                    "name": "test1",
                    "flag": "N0",
                    "hasAlerts": false,
                    "children": {
                        "147853": {
                            "nodeType": "node",
                            "name": "test2",
                            "flag": "N0",
                            "children": {
                                "NP12-N9-S4": {
                                    "nodeType": "agent",
                                    "name": "Win10",
                                    "type": "S"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add your JSON as plain text to your question

Comment: What about `$_.'147852'`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon

Edited 1st post :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert

$_."147852" as well as $_.Definition."147852" doesn't output anything :'(

Comment: `$json.data.'130333'.children.'147852'` should work just fine as Jeroen Mostert stated before

Comment: Well yeah, there's no `Definition` in your JSON anywhere... `Definition` is part of the metadata of the property, not your actual data. `.data.'130333'.children.'147852'` works fine on my end.

Comment: In JSON put as sample, "children" key below the "Test name" is the one I' could manage putting in $children variable then loop through it.

147852 is one key among several that I'm trying to access (to get, for example the child value "test2" as "name" key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I dot-reference a hashtable key's value property if the property name is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762971/why-cant-i-dot-reference-a-hashtable-keys-value-property-if-the-property-name)

Comment: Note that dot-referencing is flexible enough to handle variables as well, and by extension expressions. `$json.data.(($json.data | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty)[0].Name)` will give you the first property, no matter its name. Looping can be done similarly.

Comment: Omg I'm so stupid.

I was looping using `$children | Get-Member -type NoteProperty | ForEach-Object`

Thanks to your post @JeroenMostert talking about metadata, I understood there was maybe a mistake in it.

Changing to  `$children | ForEach-Object` made it work as expected.

Thanks to all of you <3

Comment: There is no such thing as stupid when there is learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) provided the crucial pointer in the comments, and [Bender the Greatest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584676/bender-the-greatest) links to what is effectively a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762971/why-cant-i-dot-reference-a-hashtable-keys-value-property-if-the-property-name), but given that the latter is *hashtable*-focused, let me recapitulate the problem in the context of *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]`):

Leaving the accidental use of `Get-Member` out of the picture, your problem ultimately boils down to a ***parser bug* in PowerShell** (see [GitHub issue #14036](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14036)):

**To avoid it, *quote* property names that *look like numbers*** - e.g., to access property `147852` on object `$obj`, use **`$obj.'147852'`**

Strictly speaking, the bug only surfaces if you attempt an *additional* (nested) property access:

```sh
# Nested sample custom object.
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ 147852 = [pscustomobject] @{ name = 'test1' } }

# OK - number-like property is accessed without quoting, but *not nested*.
# However, $obj.'147852' is preferable.
$obj.147852

# *Nested* property access:

# !! BUG triggers error: "Missing property name after reference operator."
$obj.147852.name

# OK: Quoting avoids the problem.
$obj.'147852'.name # -> 'test1'
```

Comment: It's a good thing we have you to dig down to the nitty-gritty of these things. My approach to solving the bug would have been to disallow things like `$obj.147852` entirely, because *of course* that's not an identifier and *of course* you have to quote it (if you don't want to use expression syntax a la `$obj.(147852)`). But apparently the intent is to make this work, and it's the failed nesting that is the actual bug. Whoops, good thing I didn't break all of that code. :P

Comment: @JeroenMostert :) The problem is that PowerShell is more permissive than C#, for instance, both with respect to `[pscustomobject]` instances and `class` definitions, e.g. `class Foo { [string] $123 = 'one two three' }`. For that reason, allowing `.123` makes sense. What does _not_ make sense, however, is to interpret `.123.<whatever>` _as a single property  name that is a `[double]`_, which is the source of the bug.

Comment: P.S., @JeroenMostert: since PowerShell also allows property-access syntax with _dictionaries_ (hashtables / types that implement `IDictionary`), whose _keys_ can be of _any type_ -  unlike object _properties_, which are invariably _strings_ - there is _some_ justification for interpreting `123.<whatever>` as a `[double]` - but to me that isn't convincing, given that binary-to-decimal rounding errors inherently make  `[double]` instances unsuitable as _keys_.