# "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: xml, powershell, formatting

I use an XML file to store configuration for creating virtual machines. My Powershell script creates the VM but I get this error where I'm trying to pass the `MemoryStartup` value into the `new-vm` function.

I tried to fix this by specifying [int64] before my variable but no luck. I can read the data from the XML file but it sees it as a string and the function requires it to be an int64.

In my xml file I put:
4096MB

In my powershell script:

```
new-vm -ComputerName $Using:Hostname -name $Using:VMName -MemoryStartupBytes [int64]$Using:MemoryStartup
```

Error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'MemoryStartupBytes'. Cannot convert value "[int64]4096MB" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-VM], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVM
```

Comment: [1] please read the Tour page for a link to how to format code ... and then format your code to make it easily read. [*grin*]  ///// [2] why are you using `$Using:`? i don't see the need for it in your code. ///// [3] you need to make sure that the `[int64]4096MB` is getting converted to a number BEFORE trying to use it. you may need to wrap it in `()` to force it to be evaluated before it is used.

Comment: Can't be reproduced with this information: `[Int64]([Xml]'<Test>4096MB</Test>').Test` works fine.

Comment: @iRon not in ps 5.1

Comment: @js2010, good point. Workaround: `[int64](0 + ([Xml]'<Test>4096MB</Test>').Test)` (or use [PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

XML file:
4GB

Powershell file:
new-vm -ComputerName $Hostname -name $VMName -MemoryStartupBytes (Invoke-Expression $MemoryStartup) -Generation 2 -Path $LocationPath

By using the Invoke-Expression it works like a charm

Comment: That is a pretty expensive workaround. Besides it is recommended to avoid [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression#description)

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find any explicit way to perform this type of casting in Powershell, as it appears to use native implicit functions to convert memory values to integers. However, an *implicit* cast by attempting a numeric operation seems to do the trick:

```
"512MB"/1
536870912
```

Therefore:

```
new-vm -ComputerName $Using:Hostname -name $Using:VMName -MemoryStartupBytes [int64]$($MemoryStartup/1)
```

There are *lots* more details relevant to your question in [How to convert to UInt64 from a string in Powershell? String-to-number conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088561/how-to-convert-to-uint64-from-a-string-in-powershell-string-to-number-conversio). Do hop over there to give the superior source an upvote.