# Argument -MemoryStartupBytes via variable

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Good evening everybody,

I need help with a simple variable in Powershell. I'm trying to auto the creation of VM in Hyper-V trough Powershell.

I'm trying to prompt via Read-Host the amount of RAM GB but I received the same error all time.

```
$ram = Read-Host -Prompt "Ram to use"
New-VM -Name $vm -MemoryStartupBytes $ram -BootDevice VHD -NewVHDPath C:\HyperV\Virtualmachines\$vm.vhdx -Path C:\HyperV\Virtualmachines -NewVHDSizeBytes $disc1 -Generation 2 -Switch Data
New-VHD -Path C:\HyperV\virtualmachines\"$vm"_2.vhdx -SizeBytes 40GB -Dynamic
```

This is the error I received.

Two of them, one from the bytes and the other the correct format

> New-VHD : Cannot bind parameter 'SizeBytes'. Cannot convert value
> "[60GB]" to type "System.UInt64". Error: "Input string was not in a
> correct format."

> The minimum amount of memory you can assign to this virtual machine is
> '32' MB.

I dont understand why is not working with GB if a put myself the amount in the properly powershell work fine but if I write in the variable doesnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert to UInt64 from a string in Powershell? String-to-number conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088561/how-to-convert-to-uint64-from-a-string-in-powershell-string-to-number-conversio)

Comment: So this should work: `-MemoryStartupBytes ([uint64] ($ram / 1))`. BTW, on PS 7+, your code already works without further ado, because PS 7+ implicitly converts strings with multiplier suffix into numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can type in anything in Read-Host..
To remove the fluff, do something like

```
$ram = Read-Host -Prompt "Ram to use (GB)"
$ram = [uint64]($ram -replace '\D') * 1GB  # now you have the value as UInt64
```